# Acceder método de una clase A desde otra clase B

Tags: c++

Como dice el título, deseo Acceder al método de una clase A desde otra clase B

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;


class Cliente
{
    private:
        int Monto;
        string Nombre;

    public:
        Cliente(int _Monto,string _Nombre){Monto=_Monto;Nombre=_Nombre;}     

        void Deposito(int cantidad)
        {
            Monto=Monto+cantidad;
        }       

        void Retiro(int cantidad)
        {
            Monto=Monto-cantidad;
        }  

        int Saldo()
        {
            return Monto;
        }                  
};

class Banco : Cliente
{
    public:
        Banco();     

        //Desde aquí quiero acceder a los métodos de la CLASE Cliente ¿Cómo?    
};

int main()
{
    Cliente P1(100,"Carlos");
    Cliente P2(100,"Carlos");
    Cliente P3(100,"Carlos");


    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[ ¿Desde donde puedes instanciar un método? ]** La *visibilidad* de los miembros en C++ es publica, privada o protegida. Entonces si haces un metodo con visibilidad public, puedes instanciarlo desde la propia clase, una subclase, o por medio de sus instancias creadas de clase. Con private desde la propia clase. Y protegido : clases y subclases, pero no desde las instancias de clase creadas.

**[ Para acceder a los métodos de una clase desde otra clase ]** Si quieres acceder a un método desde otro método, lo mejor es que este lo pongas como protected, declarando la clase desde donde lo vayas a instanciar como subclase de la clase en que esté dicho método (o como clase derivada en la jerarquía de clases, de la clase donde esté el método (clase base)). Otra opción es que esté en la misma clase (método private); O sino, siendo que pertenezcan a dos clases distintas, pues creas una instancia de la clase a cuyo metodo quieras acceder (método public), en el punto en que lo necesites, y lo instancias. Igual que lo harías desde el programa principal, pero desde dentro del metodo donde lo vayas a necesitar. O eso, o también puedes crear una clase común con los métodos de mayor uso, creas una instancia de la clase e instancias el método (public).

---

Antes de continuar, para que tu programa funcione, tiene que estar libre de errores. La forma en que has creado la clase, no es correcta por muchos motivos. Te sugiero que la revises entera. No has declarado los métodos, y los has programado como si fueran funciones. Los metodos no son funciones. En C se usan funciones y librerías, C++ es programación orientada a objetos, aquí no hay funciones ni librerias, sino clases y métodos.

---

Otro punto, es que, para poder acceder a los metodos de una clase : has de llegar a crear una instancia de la clase. En el código que has puesto, no se crea la instancia de la clase. Solo cuando creas una instancia de una clase, puedes instanciar sus metodos. La programacion orientada a objetos se basa en la encapsulación. Al crear una instancia de la clase, se llama al constructor, ahí se inicializan los valores que se requiera, propiedades, miembros y espacios de memoria que se asignan para su posterior uso al instanciar los métodos : para el funcionamiento de la instancia de la clase como un objeto coherente, integral. Luego por medio del objeto de la clase ( de la instancia creada de la clase ), puedes instanciar sus métodos. Esto es así porque los metodos son parte de la clase.

Crear una instancia de una clase en C++

```
void main()
{
    // Crear instancia de la clase Cliente ...

    Cliente cliente_1 (2000,"Jose Apellido Apellido2");  


    // Instanciar el metodo Deposito ...

    cliente_1.Deposito(450);

    ....
    ....
    ....
```

*Una clase está constituida por métodos de manera que estos permiten resolver una serie de necesidades en cierto ámbito, este es el concepto de objeto, guarda una relación directa con las formas en que se puede aplicar, abiertamente.*

De la misma manera que para poder conducir un coche o lavarlo, antes tienes que haber comprado o alquilado el coche. La clase sería como la descripción o el concepto completo de un objeto, e instanciar la clase sería como crear, solicitar, o hacer lo preciso para obtener el objeto en sí, el cual permite hacer una serie de cosas.

Comment: No pregunte..como puedo acceder desde una Clase A a un metodo de la clase B...?

Answer (score 1):

No se exáctamente a qué te refieres con "Acceder". En el punto en que has escrito el comentario `Desde aquí quiero acceder a los métodos de la CLASE Cliente` todos los elementos públicos de `Cliente` son **visibles** y en consecuencia accesibles.

Si te refieres a que quieres llamar las funciones de la clase base de `Banco` (es decir `Cliente`), puedes llamar todas las funciones y operar sobre todos los miembros públicos de `Cliente` desde el cuerpo de una [función miembro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Funciones_miembro):

```
class Banco : Cliente
{
public:
    Banco() : Cliente(0, "")
    {
        // Es accesible porque Cliente::Deposito es publica
        Deposito(100);
    }
};
```

Así que **ya tienes acceso a los métodos (públicos y protegidos) de la clase Cliente**. Por cierto, dado que `Banco` deriva de `Cliente` (puede que tenga sentido en tu contexto, pero yo no se lo veo) cuando construyes un `Banco`, la clase `Cliente` también debe ser construida, por ello he añadido el código adicional de construccion de `Cliente` en el código de `Banco`.

#### Notas adicionales.

El *acceso* a los miembros de `Cliente` es implícito, pero puedes hacerlo explícito utilizando la palabra reservada `using`:

```
class Banco : Cliente
{
public:
    // Indicas que vas a usar en este ámbito la versión
    // de la funcion Deposito proveniente de Cliente.
    using Cliente::Deposito;
    // Indicas que vas a usar en este ámbito la versión
    // de la funcion Retiro proveniente de Cliente.
    using Cliente::Retiro;

    Banco();
};
```

Sin embargo, no es necesario marcar el acceso explícitamente pues al ser `Banco` una clase derivada de `Cliente` todos los elementos públicos de la clase base son accesibles implícitamente. ¿Para qué usar `using` entonces?

#### [`using`](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#inheriting): Traer elementos de un ámbito a otro.

Las normas de ámbito de C++ indican que los elementos de la clase base no pertenecen al mismo ámbito que la clase derivada, esto puede ser confuso en ocasiones. Imaginemos que `Banco` tuviera también una función `Deposito` con una firma diferente:

```
class Banco : Cliente
{
public:
    void Deposito(float); // Recibe float, no int como Cliente::Deposito
    Banco();
};

Banco b;
b.Deposito(1234); // Llama a Banco::Deposito(float)!!!
```

La mejor candidata a llamar `Deposito(1234)` es la función que recibe un entero como parámetro (ya que `1234` es un `int`). ¡Pero se está llamando la función que recibe `float`! La versión con `float` es la peor candidata pues debe hacerse una conversión (de entero a flotante) ¿por qué se ha escogido la peor función candidata para la llamada? Porque la función miembro `Deposito` que recibe `int` pertenece al ámbito de `Cliente`, este ámbito está más *alejado* del ámbito de `Banco`, así que la primera función utilizable *a la vista* es la versión que recibe `float` como parámetro y pertenece a `Banco`. Pese a que ambas son accesibles, tiene *preferencia* la del ámbito actual.

Usando la palabra reservada `using` se trae al ámbito de `Banco` la función `Deposito`, de esta manera ambas funciones estarán en el mismo ámbito y se escogerá la mejor opción no la *más cercana*:

```
class Banco : Cliente
{
public:
    using Cliente::Deposito;
    void Deposito(float);
    Banco();
};

Banco b;
b.Deposito(1234); // Llama a Banco::Deposito(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, como han comentado otras respuestas, es atender a la visibilidad de las funciones:

- Si la visibilidad es *public* la función podrá ser llamada desde cualquier parte del código.
- Si la visibilidad es *protected* la función únicamente podrá ser llamada por clases hijas y por la propia clase.
- Si la visibilidad es *private* la función únicamente podrá ser llamada desde la propia clase.

Como norma general, para llamar a una función miembro desde cualquier parte de nuestro código necesitaremos indicar la instancia sobre la que ejecutamos la función. Dicha instancia puede estar por valor, por referencia o ser un puntero:

```
struct POO
{
  void func()
  { std::cout << "Hola!!" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  POO porValor;
  POO& porReferencia = porValor;
  POO* porPuntero = &porValor;

  porValor.func();
  porReferencia.func();
  porPuntero->func();
}
```

Por otro lado no hay que olvidar que la función puede ser estática. En este caso no necesitamos una instancia del objeto sino únicamente el nombre de la clase:

```
struct POO
{
  static void func()
  { std::cout << "Hola!!" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  POO::func();
}
```

En el caso de que tengamos que llamar a la función desde la propia clase se podrá indicar el nombre de la función directamente o se podrá hacer uso del puntero *this*:

```
class POO
{
  void func()
  { }

  void func2()
  {
    func(); // Sin this
    this->func(); // Con this
  }
};
```

Y como colofón, para llamar a una función miembro desde una clase hija podemos distinguir dos casos:

- La función no está sobreescrita en la clase hija. En este caso la mecánica a seguir es idéntica al caso de llamar a funciones propias de la clase.

Ejemplo:

```
class POO
{
  public:
    void func()
    { }
};

class Hija : public POO
{
  void func2()
  {
    func(); // Sin this
    this->func(); // Con this
  }
};
```

- La función está sobreescrita. En este caso si hacemos las llamadas como en el caso anterior nos encontraremos con que estamos llamando a la función sobreescrita en vez de a la función de la clase padre. Para solventar este problema hay que llamar a la función como si fuese estática indicando el nombre de la clase padre.

Ejemplo:

```
class POO
{
  public:
    void func()
    { }
};

class Hija : public POO
{
  void func()
  {}

  void func2()
  {
    func(); // Llamada a Hija::func()
    this->func(); // Llamada a Hija::func()
    POO::func(); // Llamada a POO::func()
  }
};
```

Una especie de pseudoexcepción a estas reglas lo encontramos en las funciones virtuales. Si una función se declara como virtual podrá ser sobreescrita desde una función hija incluso si la función se ha declarado con visibilidad *private*. Esto permitirá aprovechar las propiedades propias del polimorfismo. Eso sí, en este caso no podremos invocar de ninguna forma el código de la función padre desde la hija:

```
class POO
{
    virtual void func()
    { std::cout << "POO::func()" << std::endl; }

  public:

    void func2()
    { func(); }

};

class Hija : public POO
{
  void func()
  {
    std::cout << "Hija::func()" << std::endl;
    // POO::func(); // error de compilación
  }

public:

  void func3()
  {
    func(); // llamará a Hija::func()
    // POO::func(); // error de compilación
  }
};

int main()
{
  POO poo;
  Hija hija;

  poo.func2(); // Imprime POO::func()
  hija.func2(); // Imprime Hija::func()
}
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que haces es heredar A y en caso tener una función virtual o un método propio de la clase la llamas como se muestra en el código:

```
class A {
  public:
   virtual void metodo1() = 0;
  public:
   void metodo2(){/*implementacion*/};
}
class B : public A {
 public: B();
 void metodo1() {/*implementacion*/}
 void B1 (){
    A a;
    a.metodo2();
 }
```

}